# How to ensure Fxml method on button will be called before listener on it?

Tags: java, events, button, javafx, javafx-8

I got a `controller` which launchs a new window called `file` :

```
// MainController.java
Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
FXMLLoader fx = new FXMLLoader(Paths.get("../file.fxml").toUri().toURL());
Scene scene = new Scene(fx.load());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

FileController control = (FileController ) fx.getController();
control.getValiderBE().setOnAction(event1 -> {
   System.out.prinln("here 1");
});
```

I got a Button in the `FXML file` :

```
// file.fxml, fx:controller="FileController"
<Button fx:id="validerBE" onMouseClicked="#validerClickBE" text="Valider">
</Button>
```

In its `controller` (instance of `FileController`) I got :

```
FileController.java
@FXML
private Button validerBE;
@FXML
void validerClickBE(MouseEvent event) {
   System.out.prinln("here 2");
}
public Button getValiderBE() {
    return validerBE;
}
```

And print goes in this order : `here 1` => `here 2`. And sometines method in `FileController` is even not called^^ Like if event is down in `here 1` call

But I'd to have in the other order, because new `window` add an element to a list, and first source `controller` should refresh a `TableView` (so after adding operation)

Comment: If you want to execute two activities you should use the same action for both, why you can´t use the same?

Comment: because they are not in same controller

Comment: It's pretty bad practice to expose your UI controls outside of the controller anyway. Why do you need (or think you need) to do this? In general (though there are some hacky workarounds), there's no way to control the order of execution of listeners, so if two actions are related or somehow dependent on each other, they should be executed in the same handler

Comment: Also: don't use `onMouseClicked` for a button; use `onAction`, otherwise the handler won't be invoked if the user uses the keyboard.

Comment: @James_D I ”have to" do like this because I need to refresh a TableView and because the data are stored elsewhere and need to be modified (create the objectPropety associated) I only found the way to clear and setitems again which can only be done in maincontroller

Comment: Yeah... there is just so much wrong here. I recommend you read some tutorials and perhaps some general background on MVC designs. You should pass the model (e.g. the table's backing list (`items`), or an object that contains that) to the controller, so the controller can directly update that list from an event handler. If the list is updated, then the table will update automatically.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a [MCVE] which illustrates what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that you should be using `onAction` to handle button clicks, not `onMouseClicked`. The reason for this is that if the user navigates to the button and activates it (typically with the space bar), or otherwise fires the button without the mouse (e.g. with a mnemonic), the `onMouseClicked` handler won't be invoked.

So you should have

```xml
<Button fx:id="validerBE" onAction="#validerClickBE" text="Valider" />
```

and

```
@FXML
void validerClickBE(ActionEvent event) {
   System.out.prinln("here 2");
}
```

For ordering the events: there is no general way to control the order in which event handlers are invoked. There are some special cases, which you may be able to take advantage of in some specific circumstances, but in general the order of handler invocation is not specified. Consequently, if you have two actions that are dependent on each other, they should be performed in the same handler.

At any rate, it is generally bad practice to expose the UI controls outside of the controller anyway - it violates the principal of encapsulation and will make your code much harder to maintain. Typically you should pass a data model to the controller, and then the controller can invoke any actions on the data model that it needs to invoke.

At the very least, you can define a field to represent an action to perform when the button is pressed, and invoke it from your existing handler, though of course a proper MVC approach is far preferable:

```
public class FileController {

    private Runnable onValidate = () -> {} ;

    public void setOnValidate(Runnable onValidate) {
        this.onValidate = onValidate ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void validerClickBE(ActionEvent event) {
        // whichever order you need....
        onValidate.run();
        System.out.println("here 2");
    }
}
```

and then of course

```
FXMLLoader fx = new FXMLLoader(Paths.get("../file.fxml").toUri().toURL());
Scene scene = new Scene(fx.load());
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

FileController control = (FileController ) fx.getController();
control.setOnValidate(() -> System.out.println("here 1"));
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed in the model the good Properties, and everything's ok